# Why typescript peek references that array desturctured variable dosen't work?

Tags: typescript

In typescript develpment on editor(e.g. VSCode), I want to get variable references that where it is used.
But in array destructured variable, I can't get.

Why can't get it?

Reproduction

- using VSCode
- TypeScript version: `Version 3.5.0-dev.20190517`

```js
// mod.ts
export const [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3];

// index.ts
import { a } from './mod';
```

- open `mod.ts`
- move cursor at variable `a`
- open `Command Palette` and execute `Peek refereces`

expected behavior: got reference that `a` is used in `mod.ts` and  `index.ts`
actual: got reference that only used in `mod.ts`

Also, I looked tsserver log, `reference` command response didn't contain `index.ts` information

Comment: You try to create two variables with same name.

Comment: import { a as aa } from './mod';